# Click on location in macOS without blocking cursor movement

Tags: swift, macos

For a personal automation app I'm building (that performs actions **on a third-party app**), I need to repeatedly click on a location `(such as a changing CGPoint(x:y:))` with Swift 5.7 in macOS 13 without moving the cursor or taking control of cursor from user.

I've come up with a simple solution that clicks on destination and moves cursor back to old position, but it is blocking and if I move the cursor while doing this it is suddenly blocked and stops moving for like 0.1-0.5s when using trackpad.

**Current solution** (*which I assumed to be quick enough to be non blocking*, but I can even sometimes see cursor at click location before it moves back):

```
// For example every 0.5 second
func performAutoClick(location: CGPoint) {
    let oldCursorLocation = getCurrentLocation()

    // Click new location
    click(on: location)

    // Move cursor to old location quickly
    CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(CGMainDisplayID(), oldCursorLocation)
}


func click(on location: CGPoint) {
    let source = CGEventSource(stateID: .hidSystemState)
    let eventDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: location , mouseButton: .left)
    let eventUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: location , mouseButton: .left)

    eventDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    eventUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}
```

I just want the actual cursor to be never blocked. After extensive searching I haven't find any solution to this, or even any way to perform a fake click on location without using the actual user's cursor.

I've also tried running the function in another queue using DispatchQueue with no success.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but using the Accessibility support of macOS might be a better solution. You can script it with Automator or Swift (AppKit). If it's a third-party app, [Accessibility Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html) can help you find the necessary identifiers.

Comment: I'll have to think about it more later, but one technique I would explore is to send the mouse events to the specific application you want, rather than to the HID system. Look at `postToPSN` and `postToPid`.

Comment: Rob makes a good point, but maybe also check `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`

Comment: Any update on this? PostToPid has little or no documents. And `postToPid` seems to require the app to be the frontmost application. Can't make it work. For example, I 'd like to send keyboard cmd + [ to Safari to show previous page. Currently no luck. If Safari is the frontmost application, it works